# Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id

Tags: java, jsf

i have a controller and in this controller i get some results from the db

This is the function which i get results

```
 public DataModel getFts() {

        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        List<FinancialTransactions> ftList = null;
        try {
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from FinancialTransactions where Date='" + beginDate + "'");
            ftList = (List<FinancialTransactions>) q.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ftDataModel = new ListDataModel(ftList);
    }
```

This controllers name is ftController

in jsf

```
   <h:form styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
                <h:dataTable value="#{ftController.ftDataModel}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Title"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
                <br/>
                 <h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{ftController. getFts()}"  id="searchButton"  value="Search"  />
            </h:form>
```

i have above code. This jsf's name is financialTransactions but it gives below error:

```
Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/financialTransactions.xhtml' for action '#{ftController. getFts()}' with outcome 'javax.faces.model.ListDataModel@32ee7cee'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, **JSF** expects a **navigation result** as the method return. You have to differ in JSF between getters and action methods.

- A getter returns something to display in the page you're actually
  rendering.
- An action method can perform some action in your bean and return a
  navigation result as an `String`, or a `void` or empty `String` if you want to keep the current page.

You're calling a getter method as an action method and JSF expects you will return a navigation result, however it finds a `javax.faces.model.ListDataModel` Object.

See more about [implicit navigation in JSF 2](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/).

It looks that what you want is to load a list taking search parameters into account. Then what you can do is to call a real action method:

```
<h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{ftController.loadFts}" />
```

Where `loadFts` method will load the search results in your list.

Answer (score 0):

In action attribute of commandButton, a return navigation string is expected, which may be a logical outcome string OR an implicit navigation string (Directly the name of the next page you want to navigate to). 
But here your action method is returning a `DataModel` object whose `toString()` doesn't make any sense for the navigation model of JSF. Give the name of the JSF file there to which you want to navigate to.